# Find if a string contains a character in C++ (boost allowed)

Tags: c++, string, boost

Suppose I have a string and I want to find whether a specific character (like '|') is present or not, what is the best and fastest technique to do so? I know string find implementation.I am asking for even faster implementation than this one.

Comment: Look through a `std::string` reference and you'll eventually find `find`.

Comment: Depends on what "form" of string you use.

Comment: Please avoid "best" and "fastest" in titles; the former should [almost] always be avoided as it adds little value (the "best" way will be given in the "best" answer), and the latter should be avoided unless there is a specific test-case/scenario where the common approaches "aren't fast enough" (and this requires *having* something first to compare it with!)

Comment: @chris I know string find but is there any thing more efficient than that was my question.

Comment: There's unlikely to be anything more efficient. O(n) is the best you can do. The standard library implementation should be pretty much optimal.

Comment: @Pragnesh - In that case, you should mention that you already know that implementation.

Comment: @SwapnilS I edited now.Sorry for not mentioning that

Answer (score 35):

Use [`std::string::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find)

```
if (str.find('|') != std::string::npos)
{
    // ...
}
```

There's unlikely to be anything more efficient. O(n) is the best you can do. The standard library implementation should be pretty much optimal.

Answer (score 2):

From [this source](http://adec.altervista.org/blog/optimization-find-char-implementations-time-comparison/) empirical test done with Visual Studio 2013 Compiler shows that **strchr** routine is about **2x faster** than **std::string::find** implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to use the strchr function on the corresponding c_str string:

```
if(strchr(str.c_str(), '|'))
{
    \\found
}
```

Not sure how it compares to std find in terms of speed though...

The position of the found character is

```
size_t pos = strchr(str.c_str(),'|') - str.c_str();
```

Comment: "If the character is not found, the function returns a null pointer". So in your example, you're subtracting from a NULL pointer in that case. Pointer overflow is UB.

Comment: @namezero That's why we start with an if statement before attempting to get the pos by subtraction, so if the character is not found we don't attempt to get the pos.

Comment: @Peter yeah obviously we need to provide the character we are looking for..(fixed)

Answer (score 1):

Adding on the answer of Tom Tanner. If you don't want to do any a priori calculations you will be stuck at O(n), ie there is a linear correlation between the length of the string you are searching in and the time consumption. Tom suggested to set up an array (or vector) of booleans that indicate whether a certain character occurred. It would need O(n) once to index the string, but then you can check for any number of characters in O(1) (constant time) if it is included. The downside with this approach is that you will need a lot of memory (once you decide you need to support unicode).

As a compromise you could use a std::set or similar, storing only the characters that actually exist in your input string. Memory consumption would then be around linear with regard to the number of different characters in the string but lookup would be O(log n), ie logarithmic in time.

Of course you should measure/profile and then explain here what use case you are actually optimizing for. Until you have done so, stick with what is easiest to understand and read.

Answer (score 0):

There is only one way to do this. Just iterate over the string to check if the character you are seeking exists. You can do this by using the `string::find` function, which gets a character and returns the first position that it occurs in the string, or `string::npos` if the value is not present. You could also use `std::find`, which gets two iterators, `begin` and `end` and a key value 'k' and returns an iterator pointing at the first occurrence of k in the range `[begin, end]`, or `end` if `k` wasn't found. And of course, you can implement the find function by yourself, like this:

```
string::size_type pos=string::npos;
for(string::size_type i=0; i<s.size(); ++i) {
  if(s[i] == key) {
     pos=i;
     break;
  }
}
if(pos != string::npos) {
  // key was found
} else {
  // not found
}
```

or this:

```
string::iterator pos=s.end();
for(string::iterator i=s.begin(); i!=s.end(); ++i) {
  if(*i == key) {
    pos=i;
    break;
  }
}
if(pos != s.end()) {
  // found
} else {
  // not found
}
```

More about the `std::string::find` and `std::find`:

- http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/
- http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find/

Answer (score 0):

Given your statement that you want something faster than string::find, the only thing I can think of would be to create a class which had highly customised assignment operators which on every update of the string updated an internal table which contained the first position in the string of every possible character (256 for a char string, 65536(?) for a wide string). This has O(1) lookup at the expense of quite a lot of complexity added to non-const operations.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
   string s1 = "Hello";
   string s2 = "el";
   if(strstr(s1.c_str(),s2.c_str()))
   {
    cout << " S1 Contains S2";
   }
```